# Remove all lines containing a specific string

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a big file and I want to remove all the lines that have the word `date`

For example:

```
{
  date: 10291992
  stuff: stuff
  ...
},
{
  date: 02171995
  stuff: stuff
  ...
},

...
```

So I want to remove all the lines that contains the word `date` but since each date has a different date, I can't just ctrl f and replace it. I was reading that putting `^.*` in the front but it didn't work for me.

I'm currently using Sublime Text 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is open the Find dialog (**`Find -> Find...`**), search for `date`, hit <kbd>Find All</kbd> to select all instances of your search pattern, then select **`Selection -> Expand Selection to Line`**. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and you're all done.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to follow the accepted answer but found it wasn't working for me: the **`Expand Selection to Line`** button was not expanding the selection for all the matched lines.

What did work, though, was to switch to regular expression mode (the `*.` button on the left of the Find menu) and do a search for

```
\n.+date.+
```

replacing it with an empty string. This removes the entire line (i.e., doesn't leave an empty line in its place).

Answer (score 1):

Or faster: highlight `date`, hit <kbd>Alt+F3</kbd> to Quick Find All, then <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> twice to delete the line.